# Token expires in a certain two hours

Tags: python, api, dropbox

Good afternoon, I am making an API in which it will connect to the dropbox API, the problem stems from the fact that the token does not last long, which is unclear in the documentation, does anyone of you know how to obtain the token through the endpoint or That it does not expire, I would appreciate it.

I looked in the documentation and I don't understand it well and some video tutorials don't mention it.

Comment: Tokens are designed to expire, you should implement a token refresh instead.

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox is in the process of switching to only issuing short-lived access tokens (and optional refresh tokens) instead of long-lived access tokens. You can find [more information on this migration here](https://dropbox.tech/developers/migrating-app-permissions-and-access-tokens).

Apps can still get long-term access by requesting "offline" access though, in which case the app receives a "refresh token" that can be used to retrieve new short-lived access tokens as needed, without further manual user intervention. You can find more information in the [OAuth Guide](https://developers.dropbox.com/oauth-guide) and [authorization documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#authorization).

You can find [examples of using the OAuth app authorization flow in the Dropbox Python SDK here](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-python/tree/main/example/oauth)

Comment: Is there any way to automate the token recharge part? This is to prevent the user from having to update

Comment: Yes, if you request offline access and get a refresh token, you can use the refresh token to get new short-lived access tokens automatically, without manual user interaction. The Dropbox SDK will actually handle that for you.

Comment: So to automate it, is it done as in the examples you sent me? Or does it have to be done in another way?

Comment: Yes, the examples show how to handle this. For example, you would [process the app authorization flow](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-python/blob/main/example/oauth/commandline-oauth-pkce.py#L13) once per user to get the refresh token, and after that you can store and [re-use the refresh token to make a client](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-python/blob/main/example/oauth/commandline-oauth-pkce.py#L25). The Dropbox client will do the refresh process for you automatically.